# cannot connect to Gmail using imap

Tags: node.js, gmail-imap

I am trying to view the contents of the emails received in my gmail inbox using `imap` but when I'm running the code, I am getting the following error.

**ERROR**

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:427:19)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:551:7)
    at Socket.Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:325:7)
    at JSStreamSocket.doWrite (internal/js_stream_socket.js:162:17)
    at JSStream.onwrite (internal/js_stream_socket.js:20:57)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/js_stream_socket.js:64:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED',
  source: 'socket'
}
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1321:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/js_stream_socket.js:64:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at TLSSocket._onError (C:\Users\debdutgoswami\node_modules\imap\lib\Connection.js:151:10)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT',
  source: 'socket'
}
```

**CODE**

```js
var Imap = require('imap'),
    inspect = require('util').inspect;

var imap = new Imap({
  user: 'mygmailname@gmail.com',
  password: 'mygmailpassword',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true
});

function openInbox(cb) {
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {
      bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',
      struct: true
    });
    f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
      var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
      msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
        var buffer = '';
        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
          buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });
        stream.once('end', function() {
          console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
        });
      });
      msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
        console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
      });
      msg.once('end', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
      });
    });
    f.once('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
    });
    f.once('end', function() {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
      imap.end();
    });
  });
});

imap.once('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

imap.once('end', function() {
  console.log('Connection ended');
});

imap.connect();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same issue for quite a long while... The real problem here is that, there is a complaint for self signed certificate and I got a way out.
 Just under your `tls: true` which is the self signed certificate, inside your `var imap= new imap({ //inside here })` add a line: 
`tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }`
 And you're good to go, the rest of the code is correct

Comment: this gives me "Error Invalid credentials (Failure)"

Comment: recectUnauthorized only causes the client to give a different reason for the rejection "Error Invalid credentials (Failure)"

Comment: This seems like a code smell, but it #justworked for me.

Answer (score 11):

You may also have to allow "less secure apps" on the account, see https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I enabled "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps" and then "Allow less secure apps: ON" but still get "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and resovled it by:

Google setting:

- Enable two factor authtentification
- generate application password

Gmail settings:

- Enable IMAP in gmail settings

names could be little bit different as I was not using english version of google so the "names" are my translation ...

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me. For the 2FA and App Password, go to Google Apps (waffle icon) in upper-right and select "Account" Then choose "Security" from the left-hand menu. Enable 2-Step and then create an Application password. Replace that with the password you use when instantiating Imap()

Answer (score 1):

I also have an issue and I just discovered that Google had disable "less secure apps" since june 2022.
Simple user/password login to GMAIL has been disabled for good.